# Эмулятор android в Xamarin выдает черный экран

Tags: android, android-sdk, xamarin

Решил попробовать разработать что-то для Android. Создал первый проект в Xamarin, ничего не меняя в нем, запустил. Проект успешно компилируется, и запускается эмулятор, ничего, кроме черного экрана, не выводя. Пробовал собирать сам AVD, на данный момент он в таком состоянии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть подозрения на ошибки при сборке. В окне вывода встречаются строки

> ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8
>   emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 1665 M to 1666 M

Пытался разобраться с этой ошибкой, многочисленные советы по изменению конфигурации AVD и проверке Android SDK не помогают. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй заюзать Visual Studio Android Emulator. Плюс сразу 2 вопроса, какой у тебя проц и есть на нем Hyper-V. Это важно например для Android Emulator

Comment: Процессор Intel i-5, Hyper-V, по-моему отключал.

Comment: смотри, включи Hyper - V и поставь  Visual Studio Android Emulator и попробуй на нем поднять.

Comment: отпиши потом вышло или нет @Владимир